# What is the reason to use parameter server in distributed tensorflow learning?

Tags: tensorflow, distributed

**Short version:** can't we store variables in one of the workers and not use parameter servers?

**Long version:**
I want to implement synchronous distributed learning of neural network in tensorflow. I want each worker to have a full copy of the model during training.

I've read [distributed tensorflow tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/how_tos/distributed/index.html%20distributed%20tensorflow%20tutorial) and [code of distributed training imagenet](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/inception) and didn't get why do we need parameter servers.

I see that they are used for storing values of variables and replica_device_setter takes care that variables are evenly distributed between parameter servers (probably it does something more, I wasn't able to fully understand the code).

The question is: why don't we use one of the workers to store variables? Will I achieve that if I use

```
with tf.device('/job:worker/task:0/cpu:0'):
```

instead of

```
with tf.device(tf.train.replica_device_setter(cluster=cluster_spec)):
```

for Variaibles?
If that works is there downside comparing to solution with parameter servers?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Using parameter server can give you better network utilization, and lets you scale your models to more machines.

A concrete example, suppose you have 250M parameters, it takes 1 second to compute gradient on each worker, and there are 10 workers. This means that each worker has to send/receive 1 GB of data to 9 other workers every second, which needs 72 Gbps full duplex network capacity on each worker, which is not practical.

[image]

More realistically you could have 10 Gbps network capacity per worker. You prevent network bottlenecks by using parameter server split over 8 machines. Each worker machine communicates with each parameter machine for 1/8th of parameters.

[image]

Comment: Not sure how you end up with the numbers above. For example, in the direct worker-to-worker case: If we assume we use 64 bits per parameter (standard these days for a 64 bit float), and 250M parameters updated per second, that's 250 * 64 = 16,000M bits / second = 16Gbps (2GB/sec) *each way*, that is, for each pair of workers A and B you need to transfer 2GB from A to B and 2GB from B to A, each second. This would require a connection between A and B of 32 Gbps of total capacity (16Gbps uplink and 16GBps downlink). How do you get 8Gbps total instead?

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is to use a distributed version of TensorFlow, which automatically handles the data distribution and execution on multiple nodes by using MPI in the backend.

We have recently developed one such version at MaTEx: https://github.com/matex-org/matex, and a paper describing https://arxiv.org/abs/1704.04560

It does synchronous training and provides several parallel dataset reader format.

We will be happy to help you if you need more help!