# Pytorch Custom data loading with HTTPS is very slow

Tags: python, https, pytorch, basehttpserver

I tried implementing a custom data loader that will make a web request and will return a sample. My purpose of the program is to see if this idea would be faster than the original data loader. My web server code is run with

```
srun -n24 --mem = 12g python web.py
```

Which will then create 24 "workers" that run in the cluster. Then each worker will write its portname to a file to make itself known to the data loader that he exist. So, when the dataloader is called in the training loop. The data loader selects a random server from the files and send them a web request with an index. The web server will then load the sample and do augmentation and return via http response. From my view, i thought it would be faster than the original data loader as, each data loader worker would send a request to the webserver and get a sample. Thus, distributing data to different server so they load the images faster.

However, when i do a comparison with original data using COCO dataset. The original data loader takes 743.820 sec to complete loading an epoch while my custom data loader takes 1503.26 sec to complete. I couldn't figure out which part of my code is taking a long time, so i would like to ask for assistance. Please if my explaination is bad/not great please let me know. Any help is appreciated. Thankyou.

The following the code for starting webserver:

```
class PytorchDataHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_GET(self):

        self.send_response(200)

        self.end_headers()
        

        get_param = self.path
        get_param = parse_qs(urlparse(get_param).query)
        batch_list = [[],[]]
        c_batches = []
        index = get_param['index']
        if index :
            for data in index:
                result = imagenet_data[int(data)]
                batch_list[0].append(result[0])
                batch_list[1].append(result[1])
            c_batches.append(batch_list)
            torch.save(batch_list, self.wfile)



        else:
            write_log('Empty Parameter')


def main():
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    hostname = socket.gethostname()
    n_hostname = hostname.split(".")

    # Bind to random port
    sock.bind(('0.0.0.0', 0))
    # Get Port Number
    PORT = int(sock.getsockname()[1])
    
    current_dir = os.getcwd()
    create_dir = os.path.join(current_dir, r'worker_file')

    #filename = create_dir + '/' +  str(n_hostname[0]) + '.cvl-tengig:' + str(PORT)
    filename = create_dir + '/' +  str(n_hostname[0])  + ':' + str(PORT)
    os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(filename), exist_ok=True)

    open_file = open(filename, 'w')
    open_file.write(str(n_hostname[0]) + ':' + str(PORT))   

    open_file.close()
    try :
        SERVER = HTTPServer(('', PORT), PytorchDataHandler)
        SERVER.serve_forever()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print('Shutting down server, ^C')
        os.remove(filename)
        SERVER.socket.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The code for custom data loader:

```
class DistData(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, data, transform = None):
        self.data = data
        # Get file path
        current_dir = os.getcwd()
        create_dir = os.path.join(current_dir, r'worker_file')

        # Get all item in file
        self.arr = os.listdir(create_dir)
        self.selected = []


    def __getitem__(self, index):
        # Select a random server
        
        random_server = random.choice(self.arr)
        
        # Remove selected server from the server list
        self.arr.remove(random_server)

        # Append selected server to the selected list
        self.selected.append(random_server)

        
        return self.post_request(index, random_server)

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.data)

    def post_request(self, index, random_server):
        params = {'index': index}
        url = 'http://' + random_server + '/get'

    
        r = requests.get(url , params = params)
    

        print("Response Time : {:<10} , worker : {:<10} ".format(r.elapsed.total_seconds(), torch.utils.data.get_worker_info().id ))

        # Remove server from selected once there's a response
        self.selected.remove(random_server)
        # Add back to main server list after response
        self.arr.append(random_server)

        buffer = io.BytesIO(r.content)
        response = torch.load(buffer)

        return response

def train(net, device, trainloader, criterion, optimizer):
    for epoch in range(2):  # loop over the dataset multiple times
        running_loss = 0.0
        print('Epoch : {}'.format(epoch + 1))
        print('----------------------------')
        start_time = time.time()
        total_time = 0
        for i, data in enumerate(trainloader, 0):
            inputs, labels = data   
            print("Train: Time taken to load batch {} is {}".format(i+1,time.time() - start_time))
            total_time += time.time() - start_time
            start_time = time.time()
        print('Epoch : {} , Total Time Taken : {}'.format(epoch + 1, total_time))
    print('Finished Training')

    imagenet_data =torchvision.datasets.CocoCaptions('/db/shared/detection+classification/coco/train2017/' , 
                            '/db/shared/detection+classification/coco/annotations/captions_train2017.json')

    training_set = DistData(imagenet_data)
    trainloader = DataLoader(training_set, sampler = BatchSampler(RandomSampler(training_set), batch_size = 24, drop_last = False),
                num_workers = 4)


train(trainloader)
```

Comment: Add a log and log what happens. That's step 1 in your investigation.

Answer (score 0):

### PyTorch way of distribution

First of all, you should get yourself acquainted with [torch.nn.parallel.DistributedDataParallel](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/generated/torch.nn.parallel.DistributedDataParallel.html#distributeddataparallel) to see example how to distribute data in an efficient manner.

You can check [this answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62864931/10886420) and accompanying [Daniel's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62831823/10886420) to get some intuition about possible strategies. Also [PyTorch introduction](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/intermediate/ddp_tutorial.html) is a great resource.

In short, what it does:

- main worker loads the data (large batch)
- this batch is distributed across other workers evenly (together with neural network)
- `forward` & backward pass is done on each worker with part of data
- `gradient` from each worker is send to `main worker` where it's averaged
  and optimizer improves `model`
- `model` is distributed across workers (together with new batch)

In this case there three things send across the network (or devices):

- batch of data (preferably large)
- model
- gradients of model

This leads us to the main caveat with your solution; data transfers across the web should be minimized as those are **really slow**.

### Your way of distribution

You are making a request for **every sample**. It is really inefficient (due to network transfers), what you should be after is requesting data for the whole batch. Furthermore, each server should have this data preloaded (so four batches ahead let's say), so it can be send any time it is needed.

As you are using `14` workers on `host` and each is sending request for data to other servers, it is possible that a few of them will request for the same server. In this case each has to wait for another. It would be better to point each worker to each server.

Still, this approach isn't really efficient as the model on `host` has to wait for `data` from servers.

If possible, you could split whole `COCO` dataset across workers. Also, on each worker, there should be a module doing `forward` and `backward`. This would work similarly to **PyTorch way of distribution** described above, except for `batch` transfers across devices. On the downside, training would be less randomized.

### Questions

> However, i am a bit unclear on requesting a batch instead of sample.
> Do i send a list of index to the server and returns a batch as a
> response?

Yeah, check out [`torch.utils.data.DataLoader`'s `batch_sampler`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/data.html#torch.utils.data.DataLoader) argument.

> and how do you preload data when you are not receiving any request in
> the first place?

You can send multiple indices in a single request (e.g. indices for three batches). You prepare the first `batch` on a worker and send it to host and prepare another one (second batch) during network communication. So when you are communicating there is always one batch being prepared.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Will definitely take look on DDP later. I've tried making changes, so that worker will only select server that are not used. And it works, the previous request speed was within the range of 0.4 - 0.7 per per batch of 24. Now it takes 0.15 - 0.22. However, i am a bit unclear on requesting a batch instead of sample. Do i send a list of index to the server and returns a batch as a response? and how do you preload data when you are not receiving any request in the first place? Sorry for the long comment. I've edited the code a bit

Comment: @AlexTan edited my answer to incorporate your questions.

Comment: I've once again edited the code, so it now sends a list of index and return a batch. However, when comparing time , there's not much changes to the performance compare to load every sample. So was wondering if my code is optimize? Last i still dont understand the preload data. So instead of sending a list of index, i send three list of index to the same server?

Comment: @AlexTan Yes, you should send three. StackOverflow isn't here to write and check your whole code for you though, sorry. Your `__getitem__` and `post_request` still use single `index` instead of list of indices (batch) though.

Comment: no need to be sorry. You've help alot. When enumerating the trainloader, I tried printing the `index` and it returns a list of indices though.

Comment: @AlexTan I meant your `torch.utils.data.Dataset` should request batches, obviously `trainloader` returns multiple `indices`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219900/discussion-between-alex-tan-and-szymon-maszke).